# In Foundry Scenarios, what does the delete button do when a Scenario is saved and backed by an Object?

Tags: palantir-foundry, foundry-scenarios

I'm looking to understand when to use the delete button in the Scenario config. What does the delete button do when a Scenario is saved and backed by an Object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The delete button removes the Scenario from the Scenario array in the manager but if the underlying Scenario has been saved as an object, that object will not be affected. If the Scenario array is being loaded from an object set, the variable will recompute and the "removed" Scenario will reappear.

We recommend putting Scenarios loaded from an object set in the "static scenario array" configuration of the manager which will remove the "delete" option from those Scenarios in the manager. Then to delete them you will want to configure a regular action that deletes the underlying Scenario object instead.